# Keycloak external database configuration and Login Events expiration

Tags: keycloak

I was reading Keycloak documentation about Login Events and configuring external database and I could not find the answers for the following:

- What is the maximum expiration time for Login Events for its built in database?
- If nothing is configured for expiration time in Admin Console, what will be the default value?
- If I configure external database does that mean that all Keycloak schema is generated and data persisted in external database or can I specify to persist only Login Events there?

UPDATE: I manage to find the answers;

- Maximum expiration time is forever
- If nothing is configured for expiration time in Admin Console,default value is 0, which means never expire
- Configuring external database means that all Keycloak schema is
  generated automatically upon deployment and all data will be
  persisted in configured external data source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answers;

- Maximum expiration time is forever
- If nothing is configured for expiration time in Admin Console,default value is 0, which means never expire
- Configuring external database means that all Keycloak schema is   generated automatically upon deployment and all data will be   persisted in configured external data source